# Is there a best practice for using CodeMirror in React?

Tags: reactjs, codemirror

I am building a React based app, I would like to implement Codemirror so the user can code in browser. I have found https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-codemirror2 that turns Codemirror into a React component, I have also added the prereq Codemirror base code. I have followed the instructions but am having

I've tried reordering what get's imported but doesn't work

```
import CodeMirror from "react-codemirror2";
require("codemirror/mode/xml/xml");
require("codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript");

import "codemirror/lib/codemirror.css";
import "codemirror/theme/material.css";
return (

      <input value={query} onChange={e => setQuery(e.target.value)} />
      <CodeMirror
        options={{
          mode: "xml",
          theme: "material",
          lineNumbers: true
        }}
        onChange={(editor, data, value) => {}}
      />
)
```

I receive this error

```
Line 8:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first
 Line 9:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first
```

And when I reorder the Import I receive

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '/Users/GH/Personal-Projects/hook-fetching/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/slicedToArray' in '/Users/GH/Personal-Projects/hook-fetching/node_modules/react-dev-utils'
```

Comment: Maybe move the import to the top. The error told you reorder - to set line order

Comment: I did do that. Same issue

Comment: I lied, it still throws an error, but different

Comment: Module not found: Can't resolve '/Users/GH/Personal-Projects/hook-fetching/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/slicedToArray' in '/Users/GH/Personal-Projects/hook-fetching/node_modules/react-dev-utils'

Comment: What is that `<>` in your code? and update your question.

Comment: Not sure why it was there, but I removed it